# How to prove that the additive group of a finite field of order $p^n$ is isomorphic to $Z_p^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a finite field of cardinality $p^n$ where $p$ is prime. How to prove that the additive group of $\mathbb{F}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_p^n$?

Comment: It's a vector space over the field $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: More pointedly, we know that $\Bbb F = \Bbb Z_p(\alpha)$, where the minimal (monic) polynomial $m_{\alpha} \in \Bbb Z_p[x]$ is of degree $n$ (in fact, this polynomial can be stated explicitly, but that's not important, here). This means $\{1,\alpha,\dots,\alpha^{n-1}\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb F$ (by the minimality of the degree of $m_{\alpha}$), so that $\dim_{\Bbb Z_p}(\Bbb F) = n$, and thus $\Bbb F \cong (\Bbb Z_p)^n$ as a vector space. "Forget" the scalar multiplication, and you have an abelian group isomorphism.

Comment: Why $\Bbb F \cong (\Bbb Z_p)^n$ as a vector space? Is there any way to prove the question using the fact that $\mathbb{F}\cong \Bbb F_p[x]/(x^{p^n}-x)$?

Comment: @rbd33 _Is_ $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ _isomorphic_ to $\mathbb F_p[x]/\langle x^{p^n} - x\rangle$? Indeed, is the latter even a field or is it a ring (with zero divisors) instead? That is, is what you claim to be a _fact_ actually a fact?

Comment: why does the minimal polynomial have degree $n$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The point is that you don't need to use the explicit characterization of $\mathbb F$ as the splitting field of the polynomial $X^{p^n}$ over $\mathbb F_p$ - $\mathbb F$ is a vector space over $\mathbb F_p$ (since it's manifestly closed under addition, taking additive inverses and multiplying by elements of the field $\mathbb F_p$); now from linear algebra we know that any finite-dimensional vector space over a field $K$ is isomorphic to $K^n$ (and our field is *finite*, so it's certainly finite dimensional).

In this case, $K=\mathbb F_p$, and $\left|K^n\right|=p^n$.  So just by considering cardinalities, we can say that $\mathbb F\cong\mathbb F_p^n$ as vector spaces.  Since an isomorphism of vector spaces is *a fortiori* an isomorphism on additive groups, we have that $(\mathbb F,+)\cong (\mathbb F_p^n,+)\cong \mathbb Z_p^n$.

**Note:** $\mathbb F$ is not given by $\mathbb F_p[x]/(x^{p^n}-1)$ - the polynomial $(x^{p^n}-1)$ isn't irreducible in general, so this quotient needn't even be an integral domain, let alone a field.  Instead, it's the field generated by all the roots of the polynomial $x^{p^n}-1$; alternatively, if $f\in\mathbb F_p[x]$ is irreducible of degree $n$, then it is a factor of $x^{p^n}-1$ and we have $\mathbb F\cong \mathbb F_p[x]/(f)$.

Comment: Please, can you explain me why an isomorphism of vector fields is a fortiori an isomorphism on additive groups?

Comment: @rbd33 Well, a vector space isomorphism is just an invertible linear map.  A linear map $\alpha$ is required to satisfy the property that $\alpha(\lambda x+\mu y)=\lambda\alpha(x)=\mu\alpha(y)$; taking $\lambda=\mu=1$ in this, we see that $\alpha(x+y)=\alpha(x)+\alpha(y)$; i.e., $\alpha$ is a homomorphism of abelian groups.  Then, the invertibility of $\alpha$ tells us that it is in fact an isomorphism.

Comment: Alternatively, you can think of an isomorphism of vector spaces as being a map that preserves all of the vector space structure.  So in particular it must preserve the additive group structure.

Comment: ERRATUM (could a moderator fix please?): two comments up, it should say '$\alpha(\lambda x+\mu y)=\lambda\alpha(x)\mathbf{+}\mu\alpha(y)$'.

Answer (score 0):

According to The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups I, there are additives groups $G_d1,G_d2,...,G_dt$ so the additive group $F$ is isomorphic to $G_d1 x G_d2 x ... x G_dt$ , where $d_1/d_2/d_3/.../d_t$ and $d_1d_2..d_t=p^n$. We know that the characteristic of the additive group F is p ($p*x=0$ for every $ x ε F $). So $d_1=d_2=..=d_t=p$ 
Furthermore, F is isomorphic to $ (Z_p)^n $

Comment: Great *Analysis* Theorem?

Comment: I am really sorry, you are right. The theorem i am referred to is the structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain.

Comment: Is there any way to prove the question using the fact that $\mathbb{F}\cong \Bbb F_p[x]/(x^{p^n}-x)$?

Comment: Without using the structure theorem above, i believe it is difficult to prove. The only thing it comes in mind, is the characteristic you can prove from the given fact of yours. Another idea is David's Wheeler but i haven't checked out if it is right.
I can't see a direct way to prove such a thing using only the fact you have given.